# Mockito ArgumentMatcher lambda function with parameter not recognizing method

Tags: java, lambda, mockito

I'm trying to learn **Mockito** framework and implementing some mocks. Currently, I want to use `ArgumentMatcher` to check if the passed object matches. I saw that in the past this was possible by creating a new class that extends `ArgumentMatcher`. However, now it's possible to use Java 8 **lambda functions**. This is how I'm trying to implement it:

```
private ArgumentMatcher<User> matchUser(User user) {
    return u -> u != null && user.getId() == u.getId();
}
```

IntelliJ is giving me an error, as it's telling that `u` doesn't have the `getId` method.
Should't `u` type be inferred to `User`?

Comment: I think nothing is wrong with your code. Sometimes IDEs have a hard time inferring types; maybe you could (temporarily) help the compiler by making the argument type explicit, i.e. `return (User u) -> ...`.

Comment: This is a *method declaration* saying that it *returns* an `ArgumentMatcher`, but you have a *body* that returns a boolean. Perhaps you want something like `matchUser = (u) -> u != null && user.getId() == u.getId()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have Mockito version 1.x, where `ArgumentMatcher` is an abstract class. As of Mockito 2.x, they changed it to be an `interface`, allowing to use lambdas.

The source code of ArgumentMatcher shows that:

- [Branch `release-2.x` on GitHub](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/2.x/src/main/java/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.java)
- [Branch `release-1.x` on GitHub](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/1.x/src/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.java)

If you fix your dependencies to a more recent version of Mockito, it'll work.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.9 which has Mockito 1.10.19. Thank you for pointing that out.